# Can't start apache2.4 after upgrading subversion to 1.8.5

Tags: 13.10, svn, apache2.4

System: Ubuntu 13.10

I can't start Apache2 after I upgraded svn to 1.8.5 [wandisco] yesterday. The error I get

```
$sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 142 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_svn.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so into server: libsvn_repos-1.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

[There is no additional info in apache log]

I tried this: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1777292.html

```
$locate mod_dav_svn.so
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
```

So I changed my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_svn.load  to:

```
# Depends: dav_svn
# LoadModule authz_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
```

But I'm still getting the same error, just with path to the module changed.

```
$sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 142 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_svn.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: libsvn_repos-1.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

The strangest thing is that both files exist and are readable

```
$ls -la /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18872 paź 15 16:03 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so
$ls -la /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173224 paź 15 16:03 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
```

Info about my svn:

```
$svn --version
svn, version 1.8.5 (r1542147)
   compiled Nov 19 2013, 15:29:58 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

Są dostępne następujące moduły dostępu do repozytorium (RA):

* ra_svn : Moduł umożliwiający dostęp do repozytorium przy pomocy protokołu svn.
  - z uwierzytelnianiem Cyrus SASL
  - obsługuje protokół 'svn'
* ra_local : Moduł umożliwiający dostęp do repozytorium na lokalnym dysku.
  - obsługuje protokół 'file'
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.2
  - obsługuje protokół 'http'
  - obsługuje protokół 'https'
```

I'm out of ideas. I will be grateful for your help.

UPDATE

I downgradeg svn to 1.7.9 - now it works.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem when installing WANdisco's code distribution to Debian 6 (Squeeze). The solution is quite simple: server, and Apache support are in different packages. Here, this is what WANdisco writes on their web-site:

```
    Note: This software will install the Subversion client. 
    Optionally it can install the Apache HTTPD server (apache2) and Subversion modules.
```

Just do an `apt-get update`, upgrade `libapache2-svn`, and you're set.

Comment: I'll try it after 6.01.14, after my vacation, and than I'll let you know if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: No doubt, it will work :-) When packaging SVN 1.85, the WANdisco guys knew their job. I'm exploring some of the advanced features of SVN 1.8 (authz in the repository, XSL index page) to implement a transparent "AJAX" Wiki like thing on top of mod_dav_svn. Enjoy your vacation!

Comment: Sorry for lack on info from me, I'm swamped with work currently. I will inform you as soon as I manage to check this solution. If anyone else can check it - please do so and comment or +1 this answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same error, libapache2-svn is upgraded...

Answer (score 0):

If you look a little closer at the error message, it actually complains about not being able to load `libsvn_repos-1.so.1`. That file, according to [Ubuntu's package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libsvn_repos-1.so.1&mode=exactfilename&suite=saucy&arch=any), is part of the package **libsvn1**.

Make sure that **libsvn1** is installed and try again.

Comment: I have. But the wierd thing is that sudo dpkg -L libsvn1 | grep libsvn_repos-1.so.1   returns no results. I just made reinstall of libsvn1 to be sure.